# Rails use one auth system for two apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I created an application that uses devise for auth. If I wanted to create a completely separate application running on a different server, is there a way to have it use the same auth system as the first application?

Essentially:

```
System1     System2
-------     -------
DB1         DB2
App1        App2
 |-model1    |-another model
 |-model2    |-yet another model
 |-devise <- (Use this auth system)
```

This way, users that sign up for one application has access to all the applications I develop.

Is this doable in RAILS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [`OAuth`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth). With OAuth in place, your first application (the one with Devise) will act as a provider. Other applications (clients) will be able to connect to the provider, login & authorize, and be finally handed back to the client app. You can have as many clients as you want and the user will need to have just a single account on the provider.

There're gems that make this easy, start with [`Doorkeeper`](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper) (provider; see the sample app that uses devise - [`doorkeeper-provider-app`](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper-provider-app)) and [`OAuth2`](https://github.com/intridea/oauth2) (client).

Comment: Thanks. I'll check those out!